# Is it possible to get an uncropped splash screen in Android 12?

Tags: android-12

On Android versions older than Android 12 I am easily able to construct a splash screen with an image which is not cropped. For example like this on Android 11:

[image: Splash screen on Android 11]

However, Android 12 introduced a new Splash Screen API and I can't figure out how to reproduce the splash screen above in Android 12. It seems that it is always cropped and turns out like this on Android 12:

[image: Splash screen on Android 12]

This is my `android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml` for older Android versions (e.g. Android 11):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my `android/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml` for Android 12:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The only difference between the two `styles.xml` is that I use `android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` for Android 12 and `android:windowBackground` for older Android versions as stated in the documentation for the new splash screen API (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen).

Both `styles.xml` use `@drawable/launch_background` which is defined in `android/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/splash"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`@drawable/background` is just a `.png` with a single white pixel (1x1) and `splash.png` (1280x721) is the actual image I want to show in the splash screen which should not be cropped. I uploaded both files here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3QU9.jpg

With the new Android 12 Splash Screen API, is it even possible to get a splash screen which is identical to the result I got with Android 11 (no cropping of the background image)? If yes, how is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The goal of the new splash screen is to unify the Splash Screen UX and the cropping is part of the design.

Comment: it seems to be using centre crop scaling with a circular mask, so if your drawable has square dims it should look OK, consider using your ic_launcher_foreground asset

Comment: @hmac can u give example of code or smthng?

Comment: Usually ic_launcher_foreground comes pre made with the Android Studio. To customize it you should File > New > Image Asset